# Cant see synced Azure AD Group from SP AddIn (CSOM)

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure-ad

We are running SP Online and have Azure AD with AD Groups.

I cant find these AD-groups when searching on my web

```
web.GroupExist('MyADGRoup')
```

The users that are on the group get access to the site.

Is synced in Azure AD-groups a special case

Im using SP Online, Provider hosted app, CSOM

**NOTE:** 
The group can be found as a user with for exemple web.EnsureUser("groupname") and this user object has principaltype "Group"

Comment: What type of group is it in Azure AD? Security Group or Distribution?

Comment: Hi S. Walker. They are security groups